# Get values of multiple select with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a multiple select element:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="myselect">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  ... 
</select>
```

How can I get the values of the element with Selenium?

This is what I have:

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#myselect')
self.assertEqual('NY', denom_val.get_attribute("value")[0])
self.assertEqual('CO', denom_val.get_attribute("value")[1])
```

But in fact, `get_attribute` is returning a string, not an array of values. I guess because Selenium doesn't spot that it's a multiple element.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is Java way to do what you asking. I hope it would help. Cheers.

```
// Values into array                
List<WebElement> selElement = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select#myselect > option"));
String[] selText = new String[selElement.size()];

// Text of corresponding elements into array                   
int index = 0;
                for(WebElement element : selElement){
                    selText[index++] = element.getText();
                }
                Assert.assertEquals("Alabama"
                        ,selText[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get the values from drop down:

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
            .id("myselect"));
    List<WebElement> listOfOptions = element.findElements(By
            .tagName("option"));
    for (int index = 0; index < listOfOptions.size(); index++) {
        WebElement optionEle = listOfOptions.get(index);
        System.out.println("Option :->> " + optionEle.getText());
        System.out.println("Option-Value :->> " + optionEle.getAttribute("value"));
    }
```